# Add space after dot

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good day. I've got some problem. 
 I've got input where I wrote some information.

Example:

```
<div class="wizard wizardstep1" ng-controller='someCtrl'>
        <p class="wizardtitle">Put you Theme</p>
        <input id="taskTheme" required type="text" placeholder="Put you Theme" ng-model="taskThemeWizardInputValue" ng-change="checkThemeWizardInputValue()">
    </div>
```

And I've got my controller.

Example:

```
$scope.checkThemeWizardInputValue = function () {
                    if ($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue === undefined) {
                        $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = "";
                        console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
                        console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.length);
                    } else {
                        var strt = $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.split('.');
                        for (var i = 0 ; i < strt.length; i++) {
                            strt[i] = strt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strt[i].substr(1);
                        }
                        $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = strt.join('.');
                        console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
                        console.log(strt);
                    }
                }
```

How I can add space after dot? Who knows?

[Here is link to jsfiddle with my example.](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32384/)

Comment: On which line you want to make change?

Comment: when join in my Answer.

Comment: So you want out like this:Abc. Def. Bhi ?

Comment: Yes, And i must delete all what I write when use Backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We achieve it by adding space to each splitted string other than first one and an empty string

```js
function someCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.checkThemeWizardInputValue = function () {
        if ($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue === undefined) {
            $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = "";
            console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
            console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.length);
        } else {
            var strt = $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.split('.');
            for (var i = 0 ; i < strt.length; i++) {
                    var addSpace='';
                    if(i>0 && strt[i].trim().length>0){  
                    addSpace=' ';
                    }                    
                strt[i] = addSpace+strt[i].trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strt[i].trim().substr(1);
            }
            $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = strt.join('.');
            console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
            console.log(strt);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div class="wizard wizardstep1" ng-controller='someCtrl'>
        <p class="wizardtitle">Put you Theme</p>
        <input id="taskTheme" required type="text" placeholder="Put you Theme" ng-model="taskThemeWizardInputValue" ng-change="checkThemeWizardInputValue()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by changing `strt.join('.')` to `strt.join('. ')`.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't dislike you answer. Because first of all look how you join work and than write work example plz.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.checkThemeWizardInputValue = function () {
    if ($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue === undefined) {
      $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = "";
      console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
      console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.length);
    } else {
      var strt = $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue.split('.');

      for (var i = 0 ; i < strt.length; i++) {
        strt[i] = strt[i].trim();
        if(strt[i].length > 0) {
            strt[i] = ' '+strt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strt[i].substr(1);
        }
      }
      $scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue = strt.join('.');
      console.log($scope.taskThemeWizardInputValue);
      console.log(strt);
    }
  }
```

This is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32386/)

Comment: an second you can do this without second for, you can do it in one for. But problem with backspace still have.

Comment: Now i coudn't make space between words. So not correct.

Comment: What do you mean by couldn't make space?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a `directive` so that you can plugin this behaviour whenever required., rather than writing your `ng-change` in every controller.

In directive simple line `element.val(event.target.value.split(".").join(". "));` will work for you., with help of directive `controller` parameter.

See example [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9vs8o8pf/)